# Creating cross origin HTML iframe inside CSS3DObject in Three.js gives error

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, cross-domain

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<script src="js/Three.js"></script>
<script src="js/CSS3DRenderer2.js"></script>
<script src="js/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>


<div id="ThreeJS" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px"></div>
<script>
    var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats;
    var rendererCSS;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
        scene.add(camera);
        camera.position.set(0, 150, 400);
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        container = document.getElementById('ThreeJS');
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color : 0xFFFFFF,
            side : THREE.DoubleSide
        });

        var planeWidth = 360;
        var planeHeight = 120;
        var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planeWidth, planeHeight);
        var planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
        planeMesh.position.y += 50;
        scene.add(planeMesh);


        cssScene = new THREE.Scene();
        var element = document.createElement('iframe')
        element.src = "moo.html";
        var elementWidth = 1024;
        // force iframe to have same relative dimensions as planeGeometry
        var aspectRatio = planeHeight / planeWidth;
        var elementHeight = elementWidth * aspectRatio;
        element.style.width  = elementWidth + "px";
        element.style.height = elementHeight + "px";

        var cssObject = new THREE.CSS3DObject(element);
        cssObject.position  = planeMesh.position;
        cssObject.rotation  = planeMesh.rotation;
        var percentBorder = 0.05;
        cssObject.scale.x /= (1 + percentBorder) * (elementWidth / planeWidth);
        cssObject.scale.y /= (1 + percentBorder) * (elementWidth / planeWidth);
        cssScene.add(cssObject);

        rendererCSS = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
        rendererCSS.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild(rendererCSS.domElement);

    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render();
    }

    function render() {
        rendererCSS.render(cssScene, camera);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

moo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This code gives me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlxcV.jpg

But if I change:

```
 element.src = "moo.html";
```

to

```
 element.src = "http://www.google.com";
```

I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbnNC.jpg

Inspired by this example: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSS3D.html

Is this possible to solve this in some way to create cross domain iframes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an iFrame solution is possible. However you should consider trying an alternative method which is much faster and efficient than hacking around iFrames in THREEJS.

You'll need a server setup on your localhost (or an actual dev server) to see successful results. That being said I made a JSFIDDLE with what would be working code on a server.

LINK:
http://jsfiddle.net/vnjn6mnL/19/

The idea is simple. Pull from a valid JSON object. Don't even bother parsing with jQuery from a remote file (though of course you can).

Then run through a for loop, iterating over the JSON object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.projectData.length; i ++)
```

The above code is on line 125 of the fiddle. The section below the loop shows how to pull from the JSON object:

```
    // Individual Element Creation
    var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
        element.className = 'element';

    // Individual Element Picture Creation
    var logo = document.createElement( 'div' );
        logo.className = 'logo';
        logo.innerHTML = "<img src='" +json.projectData[i].projectLogo + "'>";                  

            element.appendChild( logo );
```

Using a JSON object gives you much more flexibility in how you present any data. Things like images are rather simple, seeing as you're really working directly with CSS.

A workflow that you may find useful, if JSON objects seem daunting, is as follows:

Use: http://beta.json-generator.com/JmXmG79 for generating a JSON object programmatically. The link will take you to the exact logic I used in generating the data for the example.

To ensure you're working with a valid JSON object use an online JSON linter. Google "JSON Validator" and the first option works great.

After you're sure it is valid, bring it into your JS scene and wrap it up in a global variable tag. From that point on you can reference the Fiddle above to see anything else.